# change a drawable color programmatically in android

Tags: android, xml, drawable

i have the following parallelogram shape :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200"
    android:viewportHeight="50">

    <path android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:pathData="M 200 0 L 20 0 L 0 50 L 180 50 L 200 0" />
</vector>
```

and i have used it in this way

```
    <View

        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:onClick="test"
        android:tag="p112"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.615"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

now i want to change its color from black to white after tapping. function "test" would trigger after touching. but all i have found changes the color of background that would make my black parallelogram to a white rectangle. is there any way i can change its color. even manipulating the xml would be fine. tnx

test function:

```
    public void test(View view){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a xml selector drawable for touching?

Comment: You need a new drawable that's white, by the way, if you are wanting to only change the shape color

Comment: @cricket_007 you mean i create a new one and exactly place it on the touched shape? is there any way i set the color to each view separately?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Drawable backgroundDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(view.getBackgroundDrawable()).mutate();
DrawableCompat.setTint(backgroundDrawable, color);`

You can use this!!

Comment: instead of getBackgroundDrawable() I used getBackground() and it worked. thanks a million

Comment: but i have another problem...i made my parallelogram transparent with border, calling test function just changers the border color but when i set a color (not transparent) for my shape, test function would change its fill color. what shall i do?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the color of individual path at runtime. You can however , change the color of entire vector.

Comment: i have 64 of this shape and want to change the only one which is touched not all of them. is it possible? cause i think changing the whole vector color would change all my 64 shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setBackgroundTint instead of color. that should alter the resource of the background.